# Can KVM roll back changes to Virtual Disks automatically?

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization

I'm currently using VirtualBox on my Linux server to run a small Windows guest OS. I've configured its main virtual hard drive as what VBox calls "Immutable" - meaning that any changes to it are written into a differencing image that is discarded when the system reboots.

Can KVM do something similar?

I've read about snapshots via "savevm", "loadvm" but I believe that's saved states, not differencing images.

What I ultimately want is a VM with two drives: one reverts on each reboot, one keeps its changes. Ideally, the unchangeable drive image should be stored with only read access granted to the user running KVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KVM does have this functionality through the use its supporting tools. The name of the tool is `qemu-img` and you can either create snapshots at will *or* you can specify at disk creation time that it should use a (different) backing disk which will not be altered by any changes you make (the changes will persist in the, let's call it the fronting disk, and you can merge them too).

It sounds as if you are trying to create something like an appliance, like a set-top box or a router. In that case you are making this perhaps too complicated. Simply make your boot disk immutable (mount it read-only) and have all the mutable data on the second disk. It's done all the time. Indeed, some machines I've seen booted off a CD but still had hard disks to store data. No need for COW disks. Or maybe not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to qemu-img. It seems I could use a read-only base image for the partition and recreate the differencing image when the VM is shut down.

Comment: Btw, I'm just creating a Windows build slave to do daily builds for some of my projects. To prevent the build environment from getting tainted eventually I want to be able to undo any changes that have happened to the system effortlessly.

Comment: My answer is not clear in the backing disk case. One can create a disk that has a backing disk. Changes to the newly created disk are stored in the "disk" itself but the backing disk is untouched. Merging is good for applying updates or upgrading.

Comment: @Cygon How do I make a boot disk immutable _and_ instruct KVM to put all the mutable data on the second disk? Also, won't Windows just refuse to boot in this case?

Comment: I have ultimately decided to use VirtualBox, but I think Allen has answered your question already - install Windows on the VM, then create another hard drive that uses the former as backing disk and mount it as the one and only drive. All Windows sees then is a single, normal hard drive it can write to.

Answer (score 1):

this can be easily scripted, and RHEV already has this functionality built in.
script to star VM would be: 1) take snapshot 2) start VM with snapshot attached

on shutdown, remove snapshot, very straightforward

Comment: And it's possible to exempt one of two virtual hard drives from this snapshot?

Comment: if you script it manually - of course